# Cloning AS Project Gradle Error

Tags: android, git, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to clone my remote repository for the first time.
I usually work on a desktop, but need to work on a laptop for the time being.

I know that I must have not included the proper gradle files in my pushes. I'm just trying to figure out exactly what I did wrong and find a way to fix it.
I won't be able to get back to my normal workstation until the weekend.

A link to my project on github [here](https://github.com/a88smith/SoundScope)

After AS asks me to import project from VCS, it asks to create project from existing files or an external model. I've tried both, but I think the existing files option is what I'm supposed to do. After choosing that, I get the "Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the gradle build....".

I've found quite a few posts about this topic, but none of them seem to be exactly what I'm going through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bunch of files are missing in the root of the project.  Normally there is a master build.gradle at the same level as app that directs the build. This project doesn't have one.

What I would do is create a new project from scratch in a different space and copy its build.gradle, gradlew, gradle.bat, settings.gradle, and .gradle directory into a clean clone of your project and try again, choosing the root of your project as the import location.

I don't 100% guarantee this will work as there may have been modifications made to any of those file that may have been lost, but this should bootstrap your project again.

Also make sure a .gitignore isn't somehow ignoring these files so you can commit them back to your project.  They really do need to live in source control.